# Operand should contain 1 column(s) error in MySQL (substring and locate)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select substring(PropertyAddress, 1, (locate(',', PropertyAddress) -1 )) as address,
       substring(PropertyAddress, (locate(',', PropertyAddress) +1, length(PropertyAddress))) as city
from nashvillehousing;
```

the first substring query works, but the second one doesn't, not sure what i'm missing here.

Comment: Look at your parentheses.

Comment: Its also useful if you show us an example of the data you are processing with these commands

Comment: Use SUBSTRING_INDEX() - it is more reasonable in your case.

Comment: Would be more useful to save the data into seperate columns as if you were using a relational database, oh you are

Comment: thanks guys, sorry im new this, figured it out, it was the brackets

Comment: substring_index() isn't recognised, only substring_index2() but it doesn't work....

Comment: "(locate(',', PropertyAddress) +1," you never ended the second paren. Probably meant "(locate(',', PropertyAddress) +1),"

Answer (score -1):

Your fist select is fine, the problem lies with second one:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(PropertyAddress, (LOCATE(',', PropertyAddress) +1), LENGTH(PropertyAddress)) AS city 
FROM nashvillehousing;
```

I believe you have already realized your error there, just to make it clear, the syntax for SUBSTRING is :

```
SUBSTRING(string, start, length)
```

A  `)` was all that you misplaced.